# Existence of sequence for sum convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does there exist a sequence $( c_{k} )$ with $c_{k} \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for every sequence $(x_{k})$ with $x_{k} \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_{k} x_{k}
$$
converges if and only if $x_{k}$ converges to zero?

If not, does it exist if we assume $x_{k} \geq 0$?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want it the other way around? I mean, else one could simply choose $c_k=1$ and then $\sum x_k<\infty  \Rightarrow x_k\rightarrow 0$.
sorry for the typo

Comment: If $(c_k)$ has a subsequence that converges to $0$, one can find a sequence with infinitely many terms having value $1$ such that the sum converges. Otherwise, there is an $\alpha>0$ so that $|c_k|>\alpha$ for all $k$. One can then find a sequence that converges to $0$  such that the sum diverges.

Comment: @ boon heT: The identity $\sum x_{k} < \infty \leftrightarrow x_{k} \to 0$ does not hold, see $x_{k} = 1/n$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @b00nheT : "$\sum x_{k} < +\infty \; \Leftrightarrow \; x_{k} \to 0$ is false.

Comment: @David Mitra: thanks that helps! If you copy it to an answer, I can give you points!

Comment: Yeah, I meant to say that unless $x_k\rightarrow0$ the series diverges, my fault!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(c_k)$ has a subsequence that converges to $0$, one can find a sequence with infinitely many terms having value $1$ (and the rest having value $0$) such that the sum converges.

Otherwise, there is an $\alpha>0$ so that $|c_k|>\alpha$ for all $k$. One can then find a sequence of positive terms that converges to $0$  such that the sum diverges.